Side-by-Side Bar Chart in Tableau
I have two survey questions. For simplicity, the first question would be “on a scale of 1-10, how happy are you today?” After showing the respondent a sad video, the second question would be “on a scale of 1-10, how happy are you after watching the video?” The results are then tabulated into a CSV file, with the question as the column header and the responses 1-10 for each respondent in rows.
I want to be able to produce a side-by-side bar chart of both questions, with the columns being the scale 1-10 and the rows being the count of each value 1-10 for both survey questions (in order to show the change).
Would appreciate any help I can get!

To visualize survey data, start here https://www.datarevelations.com/visualizing-survey-data and strongly consider taking Steve Wexler's online course on visualizing survey data, reading his books and/or his blog articles, examples and Tableau conference videos. Making effective visualizations of survey data is more challenging than it seems on the surface, and more rewarding.
